# OAuth redirect(call-back) does not work properly on Chrome for SSL

Tags: php, ssl, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, litespeed

I am working on  a react single page web app(SPA) and when google redirects to ssl version of callback url of my app after successful OAuth login  it doesn't load data from server side(Laravel app is not handling received data) instead  it fetches home page of app (it seems from cache or something like that)

but if I use http version of site every thing is OK and redirected.

here is the images of both ssl and non-ssl headers

Non-SSL (every thing is OK)
[image]

With ssl
[image]

PS: Server is Open Litespeed and may be there is something wrong with it .

Comment: I found that it is loading from react service loader ho w can I disable service worker from serving this url ??

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like Web-Server Level Cache since that would show X-Litespeed-Cache Header.

However, Service Worker is indeed a Browser-Level Cache, which needs to be set up to make sure browser fetches latest data from the Network every time.

Refer to this [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker)